# Possible to create a dictionary type data structure in VHDL?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, vhdl, fpga, lookup-tables

Essentially what I would like to do, is I will have an std_logic_vector coming into my sub-module, and based upon the first 8 bits of that vector, I want to do certain things.

Essentially this is an opcode. However just feeding this into an ALU won't work, because I have variable length instructions, and also cycles.

For example, I have to different bytes that are jump instructions, one takes 3 cycles, the other 4.

I'd like a way of looking at the first byte of the input vector, and looking up exactly what the instruction is, so that I can set different values that go along with said instruction.

Essentially a dictionary, or a LUT with multiple answers.

So, for example if the first byte is 
`0x54` I want to look up and see that this is a jump, and takes 4 cycles,  its a direct addresss, and the total length of the instruction is 6 bytes.

Is there a way to do this using a dictionary type structure, or a LUT?

The instruction set I am attempting to incorporate is the 65C816, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the key is small, like in this case only 8 bits, then you can use the key directly as address to a memory, and then initialize the memory with whatever results you need from the lookup.  That lookup will only take 1 cycle, and is pretty simple to implement.

For long keys that can't be mapped to memory lookup, it is required to make a complex lookup machine, for example based on hash values of the key and final verification of key match.  That is a much larger design with longer latency.

Comment: That's brilliant... get instructions from a ROM and use a ROM to decode them. Wow! Thank you so much!